# How to compute confidence intervals and standard error for nonlinear regression with three parameters?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, regression, confidence-interval, standard-error

I have been working on a personal project trying to emulate the nonlinear regression functionality of Mathematica for three free parameters. I am able to accurately fit functions, yet I am unsure how to report the standard error and confidence intervals like Mathematica.
**See here:**

[image]
Whenever I apply the algorithms in the below tutorials for three free parameters, I get imaginary numbers as my answers:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IgIToOV2Wk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6bCBQhwtKQ&list=RDCMUCKVGxWqAcyGibKC2RKD19RQ&start_radio=1&rv=y6bCBQhwtKQ&t=244

Is there a problem with using the above algorithms, which are demonstrated with two parameters, for three parameters? How would I compute the standard error and confidence intervals for three parameters?

If it is helpful, here is the function that has given me imaginary results:
$$c * x^b * e^{(a * log10(x)^2)}. $$

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend a Bayesian inversion for estimating confidence intervals on non-linear regression problems.  See Data Analysis, A Bayesian Tutorial, D. S. Silva.  Oxford Press (2006).

Comment: Could you please give an example with the function I have put above? I am unsure how to use the algorithm in the article.